# Your account is not authorized to deploy to Galaxy?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to deploy a new application I created by running meteor deploy appname but it gives me this error... i'm logged in though using my meteor developer username & password...

Do I have to signup for galaxy or i can do this free without it?

Project is new, I just installed meteor so I didn't write any code yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deploy your app to Galaxy you have to sign up for it with your Meteor developer account. But keep in mind that this is not free of charge.
If you want to have a deeper look in the FAQ's of Galaxy you can visit [Meteor Galaxy FAQ](https://www.meteor.com/galaxy-faq)

If you only want to start developing and code your application until it is ready, then just run the `meteor` command in the working directory of your project.

Comment: I am on working directory. This happens when I run the following

Comment: meteor deploy leader.meteor.com
Talking to Galaxy servers at https://us-east-1.galaxy-deploy.meteor.com
Error deploying application: Your account is not authorized to deploy to Galaxy.

Comment: or even meteor deploy leader

Comment: You only have to execute `meteor` without deploy. Then the application will start on your local mashine default at "http://localhost:3000"

Comment: yeah that part works, I can see website on locahost 3000

Comment: I want the website online

Comment: so after this shows => App running at: http://localhost:3000/
I press CTRL+C to close then I type meteor deploy leader.meteor.com and then it shows me the error

Comment: I get it. It was a little bit unclear what you want exactly. When you want to deploy your app on a real host you either have to sign up for Galaxy here: https://www.meteor.com/galaxy/signup. Or you have to use another hosting service and deploy your application on that host. There are several tutorials on how to deploy a Meteor app. For example: https://medium.com/@leonardykris/how-to-run-a-meteor-js-application-on-heroku-in-10-steps-7aceb12de234#.w4knak49j

Comment: I saw videos where they just write that and it gets deployed right away?

Comment: Then those people already signed up for Galaxy. It could also be that the videos are a little bit older. I think that Meteor had a free hosting service in the beginning, but this service has stopped. Now they are using Galaxy.